# C# - Filter a list of objects by text for each object property

Tags: c#, search, collections, filter

I have a list of objects that were created from an Entity Framework model, like so:

`List<Model.Log> logs = db.Log.ToList();`

I'm currently implementing a few filters for this list, which is displayed on an MVC view.

What I'm trying to do is simply filter the results of this list by text that is entered by the user, however the examples I've found demonstrate filtering for strings or integers, not multiple properties of an object.

I'm open to using a different collection type as long as there's a relatively simple method of filtering the collection by the text of its object's properties.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This isn't going to be a simple task. Imagine what it takes to parse out the text and search for stuff in Google. Though you're implementation is much more finite, you need to parse the string and then interpolate that into the features that exist in LINQ.

Comment: You can use reflection to get all properties of an arbitrary object and then follow the George Johnston's method to check if they contain the string.

Comment: @keyCrumbs You can use LINQ, but you don't have to. Your example code above can be rewritten with LINQ if you like. Also note that if your 'log' has a property that is also a collection, you shouldn't just do ToString on it, but either ignore, or parse deeper using the same technique.

Comment: @keyCrumbs also note the performance of this technique can be horrible depending on many aspects, also the memory usage... So just to put it there if I was trying to filter objects with known properties I would definitely do query like George, without the reflection.

Comment: @keyCrumbs if I understand you right, you could do something like db.Log.Where(q=>q.Property1.Contains(text)||q.Property2.Contains(text)||Property3.Contains(text)) that would return results that match either of the properties because we combined em with OR operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple and very basic implementation would be to use the `.Contains` extension, e.g.

```
var r = db.Log.Where(q=>q.YourLogProperty.Contains(userEnteredText)).ToList();
```

...where `YourLogProperty` is the actual text/string you are searching and `userEnteredText` is the text from your user.